# How to control the order of execution of modules in a Node.js App

Tags: node.js

I am a student so I am fairly new to Node.js and asynchronous programming. I am working on an API project with a testing module in it. One of my modules (seed.js) connects to a mongodb database and seeds data into the database. Once the data is seeded I have tests that run in (test.js).

Aside from the errors in my test.js file which I am working on, I have an issue I would like to solve, partly for aesthetics sake but I am also concerned that my tests may start running before the seeding is completely done. I suspect that may be the case because of my console output which follows:

```

```
dougs-mbp:fsjsProject11 doug5solas$ npm test

> fsjsProject11@0.0.0 test /Users/doug5solas/training/treehouse/fsjsProjects/fsjsProject11
> export NODE_ENV=test || SET "NODE_ENV=test" && mocha test/test.js



  [---USER routes---]
    POST /api/users
Successfully initialized mongoose-seed
Connected to: mongodb://localhost:27017/CourseRateAPITest and seeding files
[ 'models/user.js', 'models/review.js', 'models/course.js' ]
Reviews collection cleared
Users collection cleared
Courses collection cleared
Successfully created document [0] of Review model
Successfully created document [2] of Review model
Successfully created document [1] of Review model
Successfully created document [1] of User model
Successfully created document [2] of User model
Successfully created document [1] of Course model
Successfully created document [0] of Course model
Successfully created document [0] of User model
      1) should create a user with complete information
      2) should reject a user with incomplete information
      3) should reject a user with a duplicate emailAddress
    GET /api/users
      4) should return a user with credentialed information
      5) should reject a user that is unauthorized


  0 passing (10s)
  5 failing

  1) [---USER routes---]
       POST /api/users
         should create a user with complete information:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.


  2) [---USER routes---]
       POST /api/users
         should reject a user with incomplete information:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.


  3) [---USER routes---]
       POST /api/users
         should reject a user with a duplicate emailAddress:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.


  4) [---USER routes---]
       GET /api/users
         should return a user with credentialed information:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.


  5) [---USER routes---]
       GET /api/users
         should reject a user that is unauthorized:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.




npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

```

As you can see, the seeding starts (the connection message) and then I get 3 lines of output from the test module, which is in turn followed by the rest of the seeding output, and finally completes with the testing output.

What I want to do is see the seeding function complete before any of the testing begins. I have included links to two gists, seed.js and test.js.

seed.js https://gist.github.com/dhawkinson/2e83c2bdbe9af8c9f26ab5b675e8d714

test.js https://gist.github.com/dhawkinson/728fd190b9a0730a3c1e6e75a802b201

I know that test.js is not working properly at this time but I am still wrestling with that on my own for now.

My concern is the order of execution between seed and test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since `seed.js` appears to export a promise that will resolve when the seeding is completed, it should be possible to wrap the `describe` block in `test.js` in the following:

```
seed.then(() => {
  // Describe, etc...
});
```

I think the more typical Mocha way of doing this is with an asynchronous `before` [hook](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) that calls `seed`, though.

Comment: I've tried every way I can think of to utilize the before hook (I had forgotten about it) but no matter how I formulate it, I still cannot get the seed functionality to complete before the first two describes fire Can you easily show me what you had in mind? I'm enough of a newbie I must be missing something.